# How can i create a queue in IBM mq explorer and How can i connect to that queue in my local machine from spring boot application to read messages?

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, mq

I have installed IBM MQ explorer in my local machine and used it as system admin
I have created queue manager, queue and channel of type server-connection
In spring boot application i have given below application properties

```
ibm.mq.conn-name=localhost(1415)
ibm.mq.queue-manager=QMGR
ibm.mq.channel=QMGR.SVR.CON.C
ibm.mq.user=admin
ibm.mq.password=passw0rd
```

Using JMS in spring bootto read messages from mq

Comment: Have you created a listener?

Comment: What error are you receiving in your application?